# SQL Error Operation is Not allowed when the object is closed

Tags: php, sql

i am getting the following error with my sql code:

> Fatal error: Uncaught exception 'com_exception' with message '**Source:**  ADODB.Recordset
> **Description:** Operation is not allowed when the object is closed.' in E:\address3.php:26 Stack trace: #0 E:\address3.php(26): unknown() #1 {main} thrown in E:\address3.php on line 26

It seems that I never opened the document, so I changed "Execute" to "Open" and then the error I get changes to "not allowed when object is open".

```
$conn = new COM("ADODB.Connection") or die("Cannot start ADO");
$connString= "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=../Database.mdb";

$conn->Open($connString);

$insertInto="INSERT INTO Addresses (first_name, last_name, address, city, state, 

zip_code) VALUES ('$first_name','$last_name','$address','$city','$state','$zip_code')";

$rs = $conn->Execute($insertInto);
if (!$rs->EOF){
$first_name=$rs->Fields("first_name");
$last_name=$rs->Fields("last_name");
$address=$rs->Fields("address");
$city=$rs->Fields("city");
$state=$rs->Fields("state");
$zip_code=$rs->Fields("zip_code");
}

print "$first_name<br>";
print "$last_name<br>";
print "$address<br>";
print "$city<br>";
print "$state<br>";
print "$zip_code<br>";
$rs->Close;
```

Comment: The insert command does not return the inserted record, if that's what you're trying to do.

Comment: I really just want to add the item to the database. It is not necessary that I view it via return. I inserted the print statements initially to see if the user query was passing from the previous page. I am happy to remove that part, if it is confusing.

Comment: Try removing everything from "if (!$rs->EOF){...} down.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion! I removed those line items and I no longer get an error. Just a blank page with no insertion. I am wondering then if the user input from the previous page is not successfully passing over then? The statements were printing previously, so I hadn't thought that to be an issue.

Comment: What RDBMS are you using? MySQL, SQL Server, SQLite, other?

Comment: I am using SQL server.